# React Native - expo snack and local env produce different results

Tags: javascript, react-native

So consider the following simple example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

import snackIcon from '@expo/snack-static/react-native-logo.png'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>

      <ImageBackground source={snackIcon} style={{flex:1}}>
         <View style={{flex: 1}}></View>
         <View style={{flex: 6}}></View>
         <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 0.7}} onPress={() => console.log("Hello World")}>
         <View style={styles.returnView}></View>
         </TouchableOpacity>
      </ImageBackground>

    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  returnView: {
      flex: 0.7,
      position:'relative',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      marginHorizontal: (Dimensions.get('window').width - Dimensions.get('window').width / 1.2) / 2,
      marginBottom: 0,
      borderRadius: 5,
    }
});
```

So the screen contains a background Image with a flex of 1 and it has 3 child Views of flex 1, 6 and 0.7.
The last view is wrapped in a TouchableOpacity so when it gets clicked it calls some function.

The result is the following:

[image]

The view is clickable and everything seems ok. [Snack link](https://snack.expo.io/5EmDqVNDA) for those interested.

Ok. The problem comes when trying to use the exact same code in a local environment created with React Native 0.62 CLI.

[image]

The result is:

[image]

The TouchableOpacity View is not displayed for some reason. If I comment the TouchableOpacity like:

[image]

the view appears:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this behavior locally?

(i've used 2 different react native logo images in local env and snack but that shouldn't be an issue)

Answer (score 0):

remove the `flex:0.7` from the Touchableopacity, then modify it from there

Comment: removing the flex:0.7 on Touchableopacity makes no difference on local, and if you remove it on snack it makes the view dissapear

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to solve this: it was one my side.

ALWAYS look from where you import stuff. In my case the autoimport came from

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

instead of

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
```